# Perceptron Learning with 2 binary inputs

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

Consider a Perceptron made of a single unit with 2 binary input X1 and X2

```
x1, x2, y
-1 -1 +1
-1 +1 -1 
+1 -1 +1
+1 +1 -1
```

While I was looking at the datasets, I was wondering whether it's possible to learn the previous dataset?

Personally, I think we can because the data is linearly sepearable. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is indeed linearly separable. Hence, a [Perceptron](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.335.3398&rep=rep1&type=pdf) trained with the Perceptron Learning Algorithm will converge on the correct solution. This is guaranteed by the [Perceptron Convergence Theorem](http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~rsnapp/teaching/cs295ml/notes/perceptron.pdf). Were the training data not linearly separable, the Perceptron Learning Algorithm would not converge, not even to an approximate solution.

Comment: Well, let me ask you this then. I think this would change the answer. Would you get the same result coding the dataset with 0 and 1 instead of -1 and +1? Why?

Comment: @Apple pie, for the inputs x it makes no difference. For the output y, at a conceptual level, it does not matter either whether you use 0 or -1, since you can trivially [adjust the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Definition) to take account of that.